# Appending result to existing file in R using write.table

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have done a text mining on a file in R , then appended it to the existing file as new column. When it is done, the column is added after the actual content. How do I correct this?

The result looks like this:

```
Customer Names
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD.
ADCHEM
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA)
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA)
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA) PTY
Aurobindo Pharma (Australia) Pty
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA)PTY LTD
V1
tmax industrial 
tmax industrial 
adchem
adchem  
adchem   
aurobindo pharma  
aurobindo pharma  
aurobindo pharma  
aurobindo pharma   
aurobindo pharma
```

But my output must look like this :

```
Customer Names                           V1 
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD                    tmax industrial     
T-MAX INDUSTRIAL LTD.                   tmax industrial     
ADCHEM                                  adchem  
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA)                      adchem      
ADCHEM (AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD              adchem      
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA)            aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA) PTY        aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA (AUSTRALIA) PTY        aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA) PTY LTD     aurobindo pharma    
AUROBINDO PHARMA(AUSTRALIA)PTY LTD      aurobindo pharma
```

The code I used is:

```
result <- data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(b, `[`)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
write.table(result, file="Counter_Party_Testing.csv", sep=".", eol="\n", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

and then the result as well Original is converted to dataframe grp1 as Origin , and grp2 as Result , now need help with print statement to print same rows each of both files at a single row in output file using for loop.

i have used this code while print statement throwing some error,

```
for (n in seq_len(nrow(grp1))) 
{
    print(grp1[n]+','+grp2[n]+) 
}
```

Comment: What is the command you used?

Comment: I have used write.table

Comment: You should edit your question to add the command you used.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to add a `, ` between or? What would you like the output to look like (you can write a example..)

Comment: @Torxed the desired Output is given above  the result is not getting added to new row instead i am getting the appended result in first row as shown above

Comment: `write.table` will append at the end of the existing file. You should first add your `result` to the file "Counter_Party_Testing.csv" you read into R, then write the resulting merged output.

Comment: @uthsavi Ah, now it makese sense. You're appending instead of rewriting.
Either you open a new file in `W` mode and add your content+new-content to that new file.. OR, you do a `fh.seek(X)` and jump to each line-ending and append data before it. That's your two options.

Comment: @Torxed , i did not get `fh.seek(x)` !! i have moved the copy of both origin as well the result to different dataframes and now how do i join them , please provide with sample code or some functions which could help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file-one.txt', 'r') as origin:
    original_data = origin.readlines()

with open('file-two.txt', 'r' as merge:
    merge_data = origin.readlines()

with open('output.csv', 'w' as output:
    for i in range(len(original_data)):
        output.write(original_data[i].strip() + ', ' + merge_data[i].strip() + '\n')
```

This solved the problem where your data isn't merged properly. Now how you use `write.table` to present it is without my scope of normal every day use. But in terms of raw data, this solves it. You could put the end-result in a string instead of writing it to disk if you'd like.

One thing to note is that you'll probably end up with a trailing `\n` like the above example, this needs to be striped before merging with any data on the same row. Also the index might get out of range if the merge-data isn't of the same or greater length as the origin data. But that's error handling and i'll leave it to you, I've just provided a concept of a solution on your problem. Other than that it's pretty straight forward coding

Comment: i am doing this above python code with R while , stuck with console ! can any `R` users help me with this code, please !

Comment: @Pascal please, can you please help me with the above `python` code to be used in `R`, while stuck up with the console trying to import the file directly using `file.choose()`. can the `with open` be used directly in `R`?

Comment: i have done this  `r1 <- read.table(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")`

         `r2 <- read.table(file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")`

        `output <- file.create("output.csv", "w")`


           `for i in seq(str_length(r1))
            output <-print(r1[i].strip() + ', ' + r2[i].strip() + '\n')`                       but then looping statement is not executed , please help

Comment: `for (n in seq_len(nrow(grp1))) {
    print(grp1[n]+','+grp2[n])
  
}` for this code print statement is throwing error ! please help.

Answer (score 1):

have got the desired output by this code:

```
df <- cbind(origin, result)


# Move to new file
     write.table(df, file="new_OT5.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE , row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```