# Saving data contained in a file

Tags: r, file, save, edit

We are working in the Nought and Crosses game and we have the following problem:

We have created a function that suggests you to put 2 names. If you don't have any file saved, the function creates a new one. But, in the case that you already have one, we need the last archive to be edited and to add the new data without deleting the previous ones.

The following is the code we currently have

```
option1<-function() { 
  Name1=readline(prompt="Please enter the name of player 1: ")
  Name2=readline(prompt="Please enter the name of player 2: ") 
  if(file.exists("C:\\Documents\\Playernames.txt")) {   
    Data=read.table("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Playernames.txt") 
    print(Data) 
    Newnames=c(Name1, Name2) 
    Newdata=data.frame(Newnames) 
    write.table(Newdata, "C:\\Documents\\Playernames.txt") 
  } else { 
    Names=c(Name1, Name2) 
    Data=data.frame(Names) 
    write.table(Data, "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Playernames.txt") 
  } 
}
```

Comment: as a normal rule you should include your code that you have in your function. Furthermore you should edit the tags, for example what programming language are you using, that would be a good tag to have. What kind of "file" is it being saved to, for example if you were saving things to an SVG file based on someone clicking a button in a html page and that button click calls a javascript function you would show the code from the html, javascript, and svg and have at least javascript and svg as the tags.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. We are working with R and we have created a data.frame with 2 names and with a write.table we have created a text file and now we need to edit it to add 2 names without deleting the old ones. The game also assigns scores by adding or subtracting points to the players depending on which one is the winner. I leave the code below so you can see it and tell us what you think the error is.

Comment: option1<-function()
{
  Name1=readline(prompt="Please enter the name of player 1: ")
  Name2=readline(prompt="Please enter the name of player 2: ")
    if(file.exists("C:\\Documents\\Playernames.txt"))
      Data=read.table("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Playernames.txt")
      print(Data)
      Newnames=c(Name1, Name2)
      Newdata=data.frame(Newnames)
      write.table(Nedata, "C:\\Documents\\Playernames.txt")
    else
    {
      Names=c(Name1, Name2)
      Data=data.frame(Names)
      write.table(Data, "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Playernames.txt")
    }
}

Comment: I can also send you the whole code of the game if needed

Comment: I have tried to add in the code in a way that makes sense, please make any changes you need. As I understand it when you load in the old file with the data that exists in it and you write out the new data the old data gets deleted if this is indeed the case you may want to look at this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206500/appending-result-to-existing-file-in-r-using-write-table